# What does "We made the window" mean?

Tags: meaning, nouns

I was watching the TV show "White Collar" (episode: Parting Shots).

The FBI arrests a man who transferred money illegally into his own account.

Below is a comment made by an FBI agent:

> ***We made the window for Forensics to track the bank transfer.***
>   *Money's been recovered.*

What does ***We made the window*** mean?
Does that mean ***We created an opportunity***?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Note: The episode's transcript can be found at:
http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=white-collar&episode=s04e04

Answer (score 3):

We don't have the full context and I can see two possible interpretations.

One is that the agent is using **window** to mean a period of time. In some way they manipulated events so that there was time for the forensic team to perform some analysis.

I use window in this sense in my IT work: System X is taken down for maintenance on Sunday evenings from 19:00 to 23:00. This gives us a window in which we can upgrade System Y.]

We sometimes use the phrase **window of opportunity** for this kind of limited time period in which to act.

A second possible meaning is that somehow they created a way for forensics to have visibility of some information, for example by obtaining access to a computer system: the forensics team have a window into the system.

In the absence of additional context I guess that this second meaning is probably what it meant.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!  Your explanation was very easy for me to understand.   English is not my first language, so I really appreciate your help.

Comment: See also definition (4) http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/window. I'd say that the first meaning in your answer is the closest.

Comment: Thank you for the link! I agree that the first meaning in djna's answer is the closest.